# How do you only train weights on the diagonal of the weight matrix of linear layer in pytorch?

Tags: python, matrix, pytorch

As the title says I am trying to diagonalize the linear layer weight matrix and freeze all other weights to be 0 during training.  This is equivalent to a layer that simply scales the previous output.  It seems like I cannot freeze part of a pytorch tensor though using the requires_grad functions.  I am writing this for an efficient tuning method so just diagonalizing the matrix afterward doesn't help me.  Please let me know if there is some sort of scaling layer that I somehow overlooked or you know how to do it let me know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to mask the gradient matrix of the layer

```py
layer = nn.Linear(d_in, d_out)
grad_mask = torch.eye(layer.weight.shape)

# stuff happens here, at some point loss.backward() is called and populates layer.weight.grad

layer.weight.grad = layer.weight.grad * grad_mask
```

That said, if you only want the diagonal, and you want all other values to be zero, why are you using a linear layer? You can just multiply the input by the diagonal values.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

d_weight = 8
weight = torch.zeros(d_weight, d_weight)
diag_values = torch.randn(d_weight)
weight = torch.diagonal_scatter(weight, diag_values, 0)

layer = nn.Linear(d_weight, d_weight, bias=False)
layer.weight.data = weight.data

x = torch.randn(1,8)
y1 = layer(x)
y2 = x*diag_values

(y1 == y2).all()
>True
```

You can do that as a module

```py
class MyLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, weight_tensor):
        super().__init__()
        self.weight_tensor = nn.Parameter(weight_tensor)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        return x * self.weight_tensor
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I ended up doing parameters and then diagonalizing it into a matrix when I needed to.  Thanks for the help though.